# Solved-How to bulk rename IMG files in Windows

Tags: windows, bash, powershell

I'm trying to organize my family's media library, and I'm trying to take filenames such as `IMG02003932`(`23421`-`2345`) and get it just down to the numbers in the middle.

I think what I am ideally looking for is the ability to mass remove everything before the first occurrence of a character (such as the leading `0` to delete `IMG` in the filename. I would like it to be flexible for video files that have more than just 3 leading characters to delete.

I'd also like it on the tail end of the filename to delete a certain character and everything following it, such as the `(` and everything following it.

I've used prefix/suffix scripts before, but not sure how to modify something like this with Windows. I've been able to do it in Excel, but I am having trouble with the logic behind it to replicate it.

Comment: You are probably best off using regex (regular expression) and the -Replace operator against the Basename of the file.

Comment: The `IMG` prefix may be useful to some embedded apps or file viewer to present a thumbnail or autolaunch the correct file viewer. Before changing 1000s of files, I would test to be sure that you won't have to undo some of that work. Also, consider the benefits of files that are stored with a self-sorting (date-time) file name, i.e. 2020-11-23.59` . That data is often embedded as metadata inside the (at least) `.jpg` files. I'm sure this has been dealt with here before, so i you can really use `bash` on windows, then search for `[bash] rename .jpg date` or similar. .... But ....

Comment: Thank you all for the tips and for the guidance on better posting.

Comment: @empty_tables Try bulk rename utility : https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Comment: @empty_tables : Have  you had any luck with this? As your Q is now on the right forum, I'll try to help you get things resolved. Goodluck.

Comment: The code help was very helpful!  Bulkrename got me there, though I'll probably play with the code a bit more still.    Thank you Shellter, I had no idea this forum existed.

Answer (score 0):

This will work it's PowerShell. Change the Dir to the one you need to work in. To do it for video just change extension and what should be replaced

```
$images = Get-ChildItem c:\temp\  -Recurse | where {$_.Extension -eq '.jpg'} 

foreach($image in $images){

    $newnname = $image.name -replace "IMG",""
    Rename-Item -Path $image.fullname -NewName $newnname -Force

}
```